# Testcontainers/Liquibase: database or liquibase databasechangelog table not found

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, liquibase, testcontainers

I've been trying to integrate Testcontainers with a Java 17 / Spring Boot 3.1.6 project with a SQL Server Database (the image is `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU12`) and liquibase 4.25.1 for db versioning. For simplicity, I want to use the jdbc string variant, but my database is not found. If I try to create it myself via init script, liquibase is complaining about its interal tables not being there. The whole thing happened in the course of a build tool swap from gradle (overkill for the small project) to maven, and also included an upgrade to JUnit 5 (from 4) so I really would like to avoid explicitly creating/managing containers in my test classes.

First I tried to just use testcontainers with the jdbc connection string `jdbc:tc:sqlserver:///database-name`

(I tried with four slashes as well after finding [this github issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4121) about a bug in url parsing, but the suggested workaround with four slashes didn't make any difference)

I get the following error:

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Database 'database-name' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. [Failed SQL: (911) USE database-name;]

The exception is thrown inside one of the liquibase scripts. Interestingly, when I remove all `USE database-name` lines from all liquibase scripts, the tests run without problem. But changing the scripts is not a viable option.

Next I tried to create the database on startup using testcontainers TC_INITSCRIPT, i.e. changed the jdbc url to `jdbc:tc:sqlserver:///database-name?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:src/test/resources/init-test.sql`
with the init-test.sql only containing

```sql
USE master
CREATE DATABASE database-name
```

But then the exception becomes:

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid object name 'DATABASECHANGELOG'

So liquibase tries to run its changesets but has no access to its internal tables.

I'm guessing that
a) testcontainer just ignores my database-name in the URL (while writing this post I also found this quote: "Note that the hostname, port and database name will be ignored; you can leave these as-is or set them to any value." in their [documentation](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) though according to various issues on their github the documentation is not always up to date..)
and b) creating the database via initscript does not give the user with which liquibase accesses this database the permission to create tables there? This is a wild guess though, I don't know enough about liquibase/SQL Server to tell.

Comment: There aren't any user databases created in `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` images, only system databases. And databases have to exist before you can connect to and use them. If you want to create a user database when spinning up a container have a read through the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) where it says, _See this example of using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database._

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out but don't think I can use those scripts through testcontainers plus I'm not sure it would really solve the problem. For now I'm trying to use a custom image with the database already created instead, which of course has its own problems.. I'll leave a comment if I find a solution.